# Batch to copy first line of text in multiple .htm files

Tags: html, batch-file

I currently have this:

```
@ECHO OFF & SETLOCAL
for %%a in (*.htm) do (
    set "line="
    set /p "line="<"%%~a"
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    echo(!line! Output.txt
    endlocal
)
```

This works, only it outputs .htm metadata instead of just the text found in the file. Is there a way to find specifically just output text in a .htm fine instead of CSS/metadata text? Thanks.

Comment: To add, the first text available is in a span tag.

Comment: You'd need a full HTML parser for that. Poor Man's solution:  Do you have a grep-like utility on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a batch + JScript hybrid script to construct an `htmlfile` COM object and use standard JavaScript DOM methods.  Here's an example that will walk the DOM starting with document.body, recursively checking whether each node's node type is a text node.  The first one it finds that contains an alphanumeric character, it echoes the trimmed text data and exits.  The batch runtime redirects that output to a text file.  Save this with a .bat extension and see whether it is reasonably close to what you're looking for.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off & setlocal

> output.txt (
    for %%I in (*.htm) do cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" <"%%~fI"
)
goto :EOF

@end // end Batch / begin JScript hybrid code

var htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile');

htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
htmlfile.write(WSH.StdIn.ReadAll());
htmlfile.documentElement.normalize();
String.prototype.trim = htmlfile.parentWindow.String.prototype.trim;

function walk(node) {
    do {
        if (node.nodeType === 3 && /\w/.test(node.data)) {
            WSH.Echo(node.data.trim());
            htmlfile.close();
            WSH.Quit(0);
        }
        if (node.hasChildNodes()) walk(node.firstChild);
    } while (node = node.nextSibling);
}

walk(htmlfile.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
```

Comment: @FunkyJ if it really is the first `<span>` tag, you could try replacing "body" with "span" in the last line.  Or if there's an ancestor element with an ID, try using `getElementById`.  Salt to taste.

Comment: It works, with exceptions. I just think there's too many variations in what can be found in these files since they don't all follow a similar structure. Many thanks.